# React dockerized app: routes not working

Tags: reactjs, docker, heroku, routes, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and I am trying to dockerize a React app using this Dockerfile:

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
LABEL autor="Ed de Almeida"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 tree
RUN mkdir /tmp/myapp
COPY . /tmp/myapp
RUN cd /tmp/myapp && npm install
RUN cd /tmp/myapp && npm run build
RUN cd /tmp/myapp/build && cp -Rvf * /var/www/html
RUN cd /var/www && chown -Rvf www-data:www-data html/
EXPOSE 80

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

This app uses `react-router v4` and it is working perfectly well in my computer when I run it with `npm start`. It also works fine at Heroku, but there I had to add a static.json file in order to make the routes work, or else I would have only route '/' working and all other routes (like '/admin') would give me a 404.

#### static.json

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

By now I have five routes at Heroku:

- http://businessfy.herokuapp.com/
- http://businessfy.herokuapp.com/admin
- http://businessfy.herokuapp.com/admin/usuarios
- http://businessfy.herokuapp.com/admin/financeiro
- http://businessfy.herokuapp.com/admin/equipe

and they are running fine, going where it expected.

It happend that when I start the container created with the image generated by the Dockerfile above, I only may access '/' and all the routes that are working fine will give me a 404.

I tried to add the **static.json** file, but it didn't work at all. First I just copied it to the application root directory, just like at Heroku. Nothing changed. Then I tried to import it from my **index.js** file. Again, nothing changed.

What is the problem here? Am I missing something at Docker? I'm assuming I am, because I am used to React but new to Docker.

Any hints?

Comment: I think Apache is not configured correctly

Comment: It is possible. But how? Can't figure it out, because routes are managed by React Router by capturing (matching) the URL and rendering the correct components. In what sense may the server interfere with this?